# How to plot very custom line styles with matplot in R

Tags: r

`?par` explains that `lty` can be specified as a vector of alternating drawn/skipped line segment lengths.

For example `c(1,3,1,1)` would look something like this:

```
─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─
```

But if I try to pass `lty=c(1,3,1,1)` to `matplot` (or if I preset it using `par`), then `matplot` assumes I want to cycle through style 1 (solid), style 3 (dotted), style 1 (solid), style 1 (solid), resulting in this

```
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   ─   
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

instead of this

```
─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ 
─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ 
─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ 
─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ 
─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ 
─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ 
─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ 
─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─ ─   ─
```

How can I make `matplot` understand that it should interpret the whole vector as one style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So `?par` actually says that the custom line types should be specified as a *character*, with an even number of elements, e.g. `"33"`.

Regardless, `matplot` won't handle mixing this in with the normal integer specification because it has "co-opted" the `lty` argument to be a vector, one value for each line.

You could pass `matplot` a *character* vector and specify each `lty` manually, e.g. something like `lty = c("44","22","33","3322")`. Or you could create your own version of `matplot` by altering the final few lines to be this:

```
if (!add) {
        ii <- ii[-1L]
        plot(x[, 1L], y[, 1L], type = type[1L], xlab = xlab, 
            ylab = ylab, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, lty = lty[[1L]], 
            lwd = lwd[1L], lend = lend[1L], pch = pch[1L], col = col[1L], 
            cex = cex[1L], bg = bg[1L], ...)
    }
    for (i in ii) lines(x[, i], y[, i], type = type[i], lty = lty[[i]], 
        lwd = lwd[i], lend = lend[i], pch = pch[i], col = col[i], 
        cex = cex[i], bg = bg[i])
```

so that it uses `[[` rather than `[` to select the appropriate `lty` value. Then you can pass a list of values to `lty` and each will be interpreted properly.